# Scanning the contents of a directory in an app's main bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, directory, mainbundle

I have the following code:

```
var error: NSError?

let filesInDirectory: [String]! = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tmpDir, error: &error) as? [String]
```

This returns a list with all of the names of the files in the app's local directory. I need to know how to do this for folders which I have stored in my Xcode project.

[image: whatevs]

Does anybody know how I could get an effect similar to the above code which returns a list of the files in a directory. Except instead of being stored in the app's local directory, it is instead stored in the Xcode project. How can I get the program to make a list of all of the file names in the data folder?

Comment: "Except instead of being stored in the app's local directory, it is instead stored in the Xcode project" – not sure what you mean by this; does this folder contain data that your app uses? if so, it **will** be in the app bundle.

Comment: I mean as in the data is stored in the same directory within the Xcode project as the view controllers and the main storyboard etc.